# what is use of vmm/vmg in visual studio setting

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have tried to set /vmm/vmg in c/c++ tag in MFC program.But when i set this my control event is not working.

What is the use of setting /vmm/vmg in c/c++ / Additional options?

Comment: [/vmm, /vms, /vmv (General Purpose Representation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkb78zf3.aspx), [/vmb, /vmg (Representation Method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yad46a6z.aspx).

Comment: But when i add this on MFC project ,Windows control events not working.

Comment: If you don't understand what the compiler switches do, don't use them. If you need to change these settings, you will know. Until then, leave them at their defaults.